# Exchanging data between MVC 2 asp.net 3.5 and Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-3.5, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I wrote an application using RIA services in a .net 4.0 project that used domain services to communicate with a client-side Silverlight 4 application. *By the way this is my first data driven Silverlight.*

I just found out that I will need to make it run in a MVC2 project running .net 3.5 on the server.

Is it possible to make RIA services work in 3.5?

If not, what would be the best way to recreate the project in 3.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this scenario is not going to work. Your choices are either host the server on .NET 4.0 or backport with .NET 3.5, SL3 and Beta2 of RIA Services.